# IPv6 non subnet prefix ping issue

Tags: ipv6

My router is behaving like this:

I have a router 'A' having an interface with multiple 'N' ipv6 addresses assigned to it. I have another router 'B' connected to the same link back to back with one ipv6 address matching one of the prefixes out of N of 'A', now when I ping any of the 'N' ips from router 'B', router 'A' is responding back. Please let me know if this is the correct behavior.

Case:

Router 'A' interface 'x' having 12::1, 13::1, 14::1, 15::1.

Router 'B' interface 'x' having 12::1.

A and B are connected B2B on 'x'

Now 'A' is replying back for ping 15::1 from 'B'.

My opnion is A should back responding back only if 12::1 is pinged, right?

Answer (score 0):

No, you now have a conflicting address (12::1) on network x.

How it works is that:

1. You get a block of IPv6 addresses to use, for example from your ISP or ULA addresses
2. You assign a /64 prefix from your block to each network
3. You give every interface a *different* address from the /64 prefix of the network that the interface belongs to

Now you should be able to ping between machines/interfaces.